# How to decide degree of hypothesis polynomial based on cost of training and cross validation error sets?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am doing some testing on a univariate linear regression model, the data set looks like this (with a first order hypothesis: $h_{\theta}(x) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x$):
[image]

I tested several polynomials for the hypothesis, and obtained the training error and cross validation error for each polynomial degree:

[image]

```
Degree  Training error           Cross validation error
------------------------------------------------------
1       5.288842274457745       3.0175455731677676
2       5.285320881474029       3.0543977942281955
3       5.283208954701718       3.024921096737189
4       5.145151826906831       3.4763054887194134
5       5.027322983012958       3.9140874141628457
6       4.777931973939712       5.5099648419979355
7       4.7755599722260005      5.5636533323733985
8       4.762093226486845       6.011397350888932
9       4.625326390270593       4.890990481517277
10      4.622919812348047       5.088397003345729
```

Do I select the hypothesis based on the lowest cross validation error, or do a trade-off between the two errors

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a univariate regression you don't even need to do any of this. Just looking at the scatterplot it seems clear to me that a linear model will be sufficient and a higher order polynomial would be overfitting.

But in general if you want a model that's predictive then you'll want to make your decisions based solely on the CV metric, since that's an estimate (albeit a biased one) of the quantity you really care about: the [risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization). The training error will almost certainly monotonically decrease with model complexity so it's not very helpful. You could consider the VC dimension and [bounds on the generalization error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension#In_statistical_learning_theory), but these tend to be really loose since they're totally agnostic to the generating distribution so it's much better to make your decisions based on CV loss. Although I do think this could be used to give a justification for the use of $R^2$ in classical settings of linear regression, since the model complexity is so small.

If we do choose the model with smallest CV loss we'd pick the first one, which agrees with what we see in the scatterplot. Also, since CV is random you'd want to pick the simplest model that nearly minimizes it (often within 1 SD of the minimum), rather than the actual minimum. So even if degree 3 was 3.016 we'd still pick the linear model.